# Promise function working fine in Safari but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, async-await, promise, mobile-safari

RESOLVED. Working code appended to post.

Hope someone can shed some light.

I have a small function to determine network speed using various methods.
Link: https://www.hyperspaces.co.uk/hhgdev/nst.html

In safari the function works entirely as expected however, in Chrome, I get the following error from the console:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toFixed') at networkSpeed (nst.html:76:36)

For the line

document.getElementById("Score").innerHTML = "Network Speed: " + ns.toFixed(2) + " Mbps";

The Code is as follows:

```js
    function getNetworkSpeed(url)                                        // test the network connection and return network speed in MBps
      {
        return new Promise ((resolve, reject) =>
        {
          getCount = (url = bigImg) ? 10 : 50;
          var networkSpeedScore = 0;                                  // create the networkSpeedScore local variable
          var fSize = 0;
          var connection = window.navigator.connection || window.navigator.mozConnection || null;   // is the navigator.connection API supported?
            if (connection === null)                                  // if navigator.connection is not supported
            { 
              fSize = -1      
              xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();                             // create a new XMLHttp request
              xhr.open("HEAD", url, true);                              // use "HEAD" instead of "GET" to get only the header
              xhr.onreadystatechange = function()                           // when the request state changes
              {
                  if (this.readyState == this.DONE)                         // and if the request is complete
                  {
                      fSize = (parseInt(xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Length")));       // get the content length of the image file specified in the 'url' variable in BYTES
                  }
              };
              xhr.send();                                       // start the XMLHttp request
              var networkImages = new Array();                            // create an array to hold the 1k images
              var lastImageLoaded = 0;                                // track the last image in the array to sucessfully complete loading
              var networkStartTime = (new Date()).getTime();                      // get the start time for the speed test
              for (i=0; i<getCount; i++)                                 // loop to load the image 100 times
              {
                networkImages[i] = new Image();                           // add new image object ot array
                networkImages[i].src = url + "?n=" + Math.random();                 // load the image from its source (adding a random number query to the string to force reload of the same file)
              }
              var interval = setInterval(function ()                          // call this function at 50 millisecond intervals
              {
                for (i=0; i<getCount; i++)                               // loop through the images in the loading queue
                {
                  var networkCurrentTime = (new Date()).getTime();                // get the current time in the process
                  if (networkImages[i].complete == true)                      // if the image in the array has finished loading
                      {
                    lastImageLoaded = i+1;                            // keep track of how many images have completed loading
                  }       
                    }
                    if (lastImageLoaded == getCount || networkCurrentTime - networkStartTime >= 1000)     // if all images have loaded or one second has passed
                    {
                      clearInterval(interval)                             // stop the function from checking which images have loaded
                      if (lastImageLoaded == 0 || fSize == -1)               // if no images have loaded
                      {
                        networkSpeedScore = 0;                            // to avoid negative scores and divide by zero errors - sets speed as 1kpbs
                        resolve(networkSpeedScore);                            // return the network speed - good result is over 1.5 (M bits per sec)
                      }
                      else
                      {
                        var totalTime = ((networkCurrentTime - networkStartTime) / 1000);       // total time taken in seconds
                        networkSpeedScore = ((lastImageLoaded * fSize)/ totalTime) / 125000;   // network speed in M bits per second
                      }
                      resolve(networkSpeedScore);                            // return the network speed - good result is over 1.5 (M bits per sec)
                  }
              }, 50);
            }
            else
            {
                networkSpeedScore = connection.bandwidth;                       // get the network bandwith from the navigator.connection API
                resolve(networkSpeedScore);
            }
        });
      }
    
    async function networkSpeed()
    {
      ns = await getNetworkSpeed(bigImg);       // A big image should be around 100k in size for the first attempt
      if (ns = 0)                               // But, sometimes a large image does not work on poor or unreliable networks
      {                                         // Using a smaller image (~1K) will give a better result in this case
        ns = await getNetworkSpeed(smallImg);   // Run the function again with a smaller file
      }
      console.log("Network Speed: "+ns.toFixed(2)+" Mbps");
      document.getElementById("Score").innerHTML = "Network Speed: " + ns.toFixed(2) + " Mbps";
    }
    
    bigImg = "sysimages/coverpage.jpg";         // any image on your site that is approx 100k in size
    smallImg = "sysimages/blue_square.png";     // any image on your site that is approx 1k in size
    networkSpeed();
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    
    <p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 30pt" id="Score">FETCHING NETWORK STATISTICS</p>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 30pt" id="Score">FETCHING NETWORK STATISTICS</p>

<script>

function getNetworkSpeed(url)                                        // test the network connection and return network speed in MBps
  {
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) =>
    {
      getCount = (url = bigImg) ? 10 : 50;
      var networkSpeedScore = 0;                                  // create the networkSpeedScore local variable
      var fSize = -1      
      xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();                             // create a new XMLHttp request
      xhr.open("HEAD", url, true);                              // use "HEAD" instead of "GET" to get only the header
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function()                           // when the request state changes
      {
          if (this.readyState == this.DONE)                         // and if the request is complete
          {
              fSize = (parseInt(xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Length")));       // get the content length of the image file specified in the 'url' variable in BYTES
          }
      };
      xhr.send();                                       // start the XMLHttp request
      var networkImages = new Array();                            // create an array to hold the 1k images
      var lastImageLoaded = 0;                                // track the last image in the array to sucessfully complete loading
      var networkStartTime = (new Date()).getTime();                      // get the start time for the speed test
      for (i=0; i<getCount; i++)                                 // loop to load the image 100 times
      {
        networkImages[i] = new Image();                           // add new image object ot array
        networkImages[i].src = url + "?n=" + Math.random();                 // load the image from its source (adding a random number query to the string to force reload of the same file)
      }
      var interval = setInterval(function ()                          // call this function at 50 millisecond intervals
      {
        for (i=0; i<getCount; i++)                               // loop through the images in the loading queue
        {
          var networkCurrentTime = (new Date()).getTime();                // get the current time in the process
          if (networkImages[i].complete == true)                      // if the image in the array has finished loading
              {
            lastImageLoaded = i+1;                            // keep track of how many images have completed loading
          }       
            }
            if (lastImageLoaded == getCount || networkCurrentTime - networkStartTime >= 1000)     // if all images have loaded or one second has passed
            {
              clearInterval(interval)                             // stop the function from checking which images have loaded
              if (lastImageLoaded == 0 || fSize == -1)               // if no images have loaded
              {
                networkSpeedScore = 0;                            // to avoid negative scores and divide by zero errors - sets speed as 1kpbs
              }
              else
              {
                var totalTime = ((networkCurrentTime - networkStartTime) / 1000);       // total time taken in seconds
                networkSpeedScore = ((lastImageLoaded * fSize)/ totalTime) / 125000;   // network speed in M bits per second
              }
              resolve(networkSpeedScore);                            // return the network speed - good result is over 1.5 (M bits per sec)
          }
      }, 50);
    });
  }

async function networkSpeed()
{
  ns = await getNetworkSpeed(bigImg);   // A big image should be around 100k in size for the first attempt
  if (ns == 0)               // But, sometimes a large image does not work on poor or unreliable networks
  {                     // Using a smaller image (~1K) will give a better result in this case
    ns = await getNetworkSpeed(smallImg); // Run the function again with a smaller file
  }
  document.getElementById("Score").innerHTML = "Network Speed: " + ns.toFixed(2) + " Mbps";
}

bigImg = "sysimages/coverpage.jpg";     // any image on your site that is approx 100k in size
smallImg = "sysimages/blue_square.png";   // any image on your site that is approx 1k in size
networkSpeed();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I converted your code to a runnable snippet. It is running for me in Chrome - I don't see your promise error message

Comment: Try running in Chrome on the desktop or mobile. I get the error in both cases.

Comment: On chromium, for me, `navigator.connection.bandwidth` is undefined. [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NetworkInformation) seem to indicate the property might be called `downlink` not `bandwidth`.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. I shall investigate.

Comment: You _really_ should have a look at `await fetch(url);` instead of this massive and complicated Promise wrapping a whole wall of `new XMLHttpRequest()`, `xhr.open`, `xhr.onreadystatechange`, `if (this.readyState == this.DONE)`, `xhr.send()` etc.

Comment: `if (ns = 0)` will set the value of ns to zero.  Maybe you want `if (ns == 0)`

Comment: You were all right. The idea of this function is to reliably ascertain network speed on all possible platforms and navigator.connection API support variants.
The code has now been amended and functions well across all desktop / mobile clients. Question altered to reflect new code.